# Can a moderator with less then 20k reputation close my question as duplicate?

Tags: support

Can a moderator with less then 20k reputation close my question as duplicate or off-topic? For example, a moderator with 1k or more reputation.

Comment: i'm quite sure they can though the likelihood of a mod electorate with less than 3k in rep being elected is unlikely because they have a lack of experience with both closing questions (at 3k rep) and using the mod tools (at 10k rep)

Comment: Maybe "moderator" here is being used in a general sense instead of diamond star. If so, any user with 3k+ rep can vote to close as dupe/OT. Any user with a gold tag badge can close immediately without voting, but it'd be hard to find a gold tag badge user without a very high rep.

Comment: Considering that for a gold badge you have to get 1000 score, it would be 1000x10rep=10000rep... even with caps, anyone should manage.

Comment: @Braiam That brings up an interesting question what if a user is able to get the badge but unlucky enough to hit the rep cap and not get past 3k rep for the privilege. Though that would be a very rare case.

Comment: @JoeW remember the other condition: 200 answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two distinctions you need to make:

- Diamond moderators (with a ♦ after their name, either elected or Stack Exchange employees) versus ordinary users that have gained some moderation privileges.
- Participate in closing a question versus closing a question with a single vote.

Anyone with the privilege to cast flags (15 rep) can participate in closing any question (except locked or deleted ones). Flags feed various review queues where other users can help triage the posts.

Ordinary users with 3k reputation or more can cast votes to close a question. Five such votes are required.

Ordinary users with a gold badge in one of the question's tags can additionally close a question as a duplicate with a single vote. (But only duplicates as of now, off-topic or other close reasons still need five votes.)

Moderators (♦) can close (and delete) anything with a single vote. No reputation requirements. But note that to get elected as a mod on Stack Overflow, you need at least 3k reputation.